# Tkinter canvas create image multiple times

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I use this function in my code to create an image on a canvas:

```
def _create_image(self, coord):
    (x,y) = coord 
    self.one = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.jpg"))
    root.one = self.one
    self.canvas.create_image(x-25, y-25, image=self.one, anchor='nw', tags="image")
```

My problem is that everytime i call this function the old image is deleted and a new one is created.

How do i prevent the old image from being deleted? I want to create the image multiple times on my canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an tkinter image canvas in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667013/using-an-tkinter-image-canvas-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a list in for example `__init__()`.

```
self.img_ref = []
```

Then append each new image to this list as you create them:

```
def _create_image(self, coord):
    (x,y) = coord 
    self.one = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.jpg"))
    root.one = self.one
    self.canvas.create_image(x-25, y-25, image=self.one,
                             anchor='nw', tags="image")
    self.img_ref.append(self.one)  # Keep reference to image
```

Even if every image is the same image you have to keep a reference to each one.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** need to modify the `__init__()` method nor store a list of references since it's always the same image file. Here something that avoids using unnecessary resource, so would therefore use less memory (and likely be faster, too).

It accomplishes this by testing to see whether the `one` attribute already exists or not, and if not, only then reads the image data and creates the `PImageTk.PhotoImagehotoImage` that first time.

This approach allows you to create multiple `Canvas` widget image objects from the same `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, instead of loading multiple copies of it into memory.

```
def _create_image(self, coord):
    (x,y) = coord

    if not getattr(self, 'one', None):  # First call?
        pil_img = Image.open("test.jpg")
        self.one = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)

    self.canvas.create_image(x-25, y-25, image=self.one,
                             anchor='nw', tags="image")
```

You could also do the creation of the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` all in one line:

```
    # pil_img = Image.open("test.jpg")  # Leave out.
    self.one = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="test.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Martineau for his input on this one. ImageTk variables seem to work if kept separate and not re-used. Else they keep the same filepath even if its new instance. I managed to draw multiple different images to canvas by keeping separate variables of ImageTk

```
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


    root = tk.Tk 
    root.mainloop()

    self.ph = [] #keep photoimage instances separate
    
    def appendImages(self):  #Call appendImages as many times as needed
        path = askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",  filetypes(("all files", "*.*"),("jpeg files", ".jpg")))
        im = Image.open(path)
        self.ph.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im))
        self.canvasImage=self.canvas.create_image(x,y,anchor=NW,image=self.ph[len(self.ph)-1])
```

The last line draws the most recent image picked the user

Comment: This works well. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`Image.open()` will rewrite the image each time.

Comment: Calling `Image.open()` multiple times wouldn't rewrite anything, it will return a new PIL image object each time.

Comment: @martineau ah yes i apologize i must have confused this with something else